# How to get the target of a Drag Drop operation on a TreeViewDragDropTarget in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, treeview, drag-and-drop

I've looked at the Drop and ItemDroppedOn Target event handlers but it appears that you can only access the source. The sender is the TreeViewDragDropTarget when I actually want to see the item in the TreeView that is being dropped on.

Comment: Unfortunately does not really work... Gives the data context of the element containing the exact co-ordinate where drop occured (e.OriginalSource)...
Howevfr this is not always the new parent... it can be also sibling if you drop it close to ah edge of e.OriginalSource...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void drag_Drop(object sender, Microsoft.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
{
    ((System.Windows.FrameworkElement)(e.OriginalSource)).DataContext
```

Is what I was looking for